# Correlation for a Data Frame with 30K columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to find a correlation of a DF with 30K columns and 100 rows.

### EX- i have to find corr of p1 with p2,p2,p3,.....p30000 and similarly p2 with remaining one and so on.

I am running it in window 10 having 16GB RAM.
It is showing Error "Memory canot be allocated"

```
col1 col2 col3
p1    p2   p3
1     3    0
3     5    7
4     3    1
```

Is there any other way with this limited computational capacity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated [here (site without secure connection)](http://gouthamanbalaraman.com/blog/numpy-vs-pandas-comparison.html):

- numpy consumes less memory compared to pandas
- numpy generally performs better than pandas for 50K rows or less
- pandas generally performs better than numpy for 500K rows or more
- for 50K to 500K rows, it is a toss up between pandas and numpy depending on the kind of operation

Guess this means the same for rows as for columns.

Therefore maybe using [numpy.correlate](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.correlate.html) is worth a try?

Comment: Issue is that with np.correlate() we can generate correlation of 2 columns only at one go.